# UNIX Function - cd .. and then move working dir

Tags: function, unix

I am trying to make a function that simply cd out of the working folder, and then moves that folder to somewhere else.  However, when attempting this, I get a cannot move error, presumably because the folder is in use because that is where I launched the function.

e.g.

```
test() {
    cpath=$(pwd)
    cd ..
    mv $cpath $cpath"old"
    cd $cpath"old"
}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing the directory **in a different process**. From your script you cannot touch the environment of the parent, unless you `source` it.